# Can I add my own themes to the new Theme section in the Personalize settings?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, themes

The latest update to KitKat 4.4.2 on my HTC ONE added a new Theme section to my Personalize settings. Right now, it just lists out four pre-defined themes, which appear to just be a wallpaper and a set of colors which control the global theme of the phone and apps.

[image: Personalize > Theme Screen]

Currently, the most bearable for me is the all black one, but the button colors with it are green which is kind of annoying me. I'd love to be able to modify them to be blue, but I don't see any way to modify the themes or even add my own. There's no additional menu when viewing that screen, no popup for long-pressing a theme, nothing. You can only select one and click Apply.

Is there a simple way to add my own themes to this list, or is there even a way to add themes to this list?

Comment: As far as I recall you have to install the themes as an .apk file, and you can't uninstall them afterwards. Head to XDA for your device model and into the 'themes and apps' section and see if anything is there. http://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-one/themes-apps